# What does glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1) accomplish?

Tags: c, opengl

I'm reading [the documentation for glOrtho](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glOrtho.xml) and not understanding it.

I'm looking at this resize code for an 2D drawing and not getting why some of the index are positive and some negative. The drawing is supposed to stay flat so I don't know if its doing what's supposed to:

```
void reshape(int width, int height)
{

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity(); 
    glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1); 
   //left, right, bottom, top, nearval, farval 
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's constructing the projection matrix. `glOrtho` multiplies the current matrix,which is the identity matrix due to the previous statement, by the orthographic projection matrix specified by the function.

Specifically, this call to `glOrtho` is constructing a matrix that will put world co-ordinates of (-1, -1, -1) at the bottom-left-front of the screen, and world co-ordinates of (1, 1, 1) at the top-right-back of the screen. So if you were to draw the triangle:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glVertex3f(-1, -1, 0);
glVertex3f(-1, 1, 0);
glVertex3f(1, -1, 0);
glEnd();
```

It would cover exactly half of the screen.

Note that if you're only using 2D then the last two parameters aren't that important (although they can be used to control layers). Just draw everything with *z=0*, and if you need to put something in front of something else then use a higher *z* value.

Comment: what would glOrtho(0.0f, windowWidth, windowHeight, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); accomplish? The limits of the world would be windowWidth and and WindowHeight, right?

Comment: Correct, although you'd have to be careful drawing with z=0 as it would be right on the edge of the z-domain (anything with z<0 or z>1 would be hidden). If you plan on drawing at z=0 then it's best to just make the range something like (-1, +1) for safety's sake.

Answer (score 2):

It actually does nothing except flip the z coordinate. If you plug in your values you'll see that it generates the matrix

```
1  0  0  0
0  1  0  0
0  0 -1  0
0  0  0  1
```

Note that it's *not* the identity matrix because `glOrtho` is <s>weird</s> stupid (note the minus signs):

> `(left, bottom, -nearVal)` and `(right, top, -nearVal)` specify the points on the near clipping plane that are mapped to the lower left and upper right corners of the window, respectively, assuming that the eye is located at (0, 0, 0).  `-farVal` specifies the location of the far clipping plane.

These minus signs mean that `fNear` and `fFar` have the opposite meaning.